# SharePoint TimerJobs and threading

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've written a SharePoint 2010 app that uses a TimerJob to trigger processing of some documents in a list. The timer is set to trigger every minute but the the processing may take more than a minute. I'm just wondering if the next trigger of the timer job will be started using a new thread, or will the timer service just wait until the first thread has completed. I have no idea how Sharepoint manages threads for TimerJobs and I can't really find any relevant information.

This is possibly a problem given that my `TimerJob` definition has the following:

```
 public override void Execute(Guid contentDbId)
    {
        try
        {
            SPWebApplication webApplication = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
            SPContentDatabase contentDb = webApplication.ContentDatabases[contentDbId];
            using (SPSite site = contentDb.Sites[0])
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
                {                       
                    PRManager.TriggerProcessing(web);    // ?                   
                }
            }
        }                      
        catch (Exception)
        { 
        }
    }
}
```

The `PRManager.TriggerProcessing()` is a static method, obviously, and while it does contain mechanisms to limit only one thread at a time entering the method body, I'm just wondering IF SharePoint does create multiple threads in the event that those at-minute-interval calls to execute overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is not so much a "thread" thing as much as it is a "job" thing.

SharePoint stores all jobs in a database table and it uses this table to track what is running and where it is running.  It has a built in synchronization engine that is responsible for making sure the jobs execute as the job instructions say.

> For example take the deployment ask
>   which is nothing more than a job.  The
>   deployment task only allows One job to
>   run for a given solution at a time. 
>   It makes sure that all of the tasks
>   finish on each server in the farm
>   before the overall job is reported as
>   done.

So the answer will depend on how your job configuration properties are set.  There is a property on that job that tells SharePoint to only allow one instance of that job to run at a time.  So if the job is currently executing another instance of it will not be started.

Comment: Cheers man. When you say "Job configuration properties", do you mean some "one job at a time" type property of the actual SPJobDefinition I've created?